# Is there a benefit to using STORING clause on an INTERLEAVE secondary index in Cloud Spanner?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

If we are using the Interleave option with a secondary index, is there still benefit to using the storing clause?

https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/secondary-indexes

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there can still be benefit, although it's less likely to be a major benefit:

Let's say you have interleaved tables Singers->Albums->Songs, and you have an index:

```
CREATE INDEX SongsBySingerSongName ON Songs(SingerId, SongName),
    INTERLEAVE IN Singers
```

Let's also assume that `Songs` has a `FLOAT64` column, `LengthInSeconds`, for storing the length of a song.

If you wanted to look up all songs for `SingerId` 123 that started with "T" and were less than 4 minutes long, your query could be executed by:

1. Using `SongsBySingerSongName` to lookup all songs for Singer 123
   that start with "T"
2. For these songs, back-join with `Songs` to
   lookup `LengthInSeconds` to filter by length.

Since both `Songs` and `SongsBySingerSongName` are interleaved in the `Singers` table, we know that our data should all be in the same [split](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/schema-and-data-model#database-splits), which means it will all reside on the same machine, which means the back-join in step (2) won't be terribly costly. However, the local back-join still incurs a cost to lookup the data, so saving step (2) by having a `STORING` clause could still reduce your query latency and overall cost.  You would want to do benchmarking of your workload to see if the extra storing clause provides a net-benefit.

In general, if you have filters in your query that refer to columns in the index (either key columns or 'storing' columns), the filters can be evaluated before doing the back-join to the base table, and if the filter does not match, the back-join can be avoided. If the filter refers to a column that is not in the index, the back-join has to be done first to get the column value that the filter refers